# SSRS report fast in Visual Studio but slow in browser

Tags: performance, reporting-services

I have an Oracle query that runs very fast in TOAD. Also, in Visual Studio, set up with a report, everything run very fast. But after deploying to SSRS site, using the same data source, the report take a long time to load.

Does anyone know why, or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Within SSRS, there are three times recorded when running a report: data retrieval time, processing time, and rendering time.  In addition to this, the output of the report must be sent across the network to your browser and rendered there for display.

First, verify that the time in SSRS is what you expect, using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    ReportPath,
    RequestType,
    TimeDataRetrieval,
    TimeProcessing,
    TimeRendering
FROM 
    [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog2] with (nolock)
WHERE
    ReportPath =  '/whatever/report'
```

Even if the data retrieval time is small, it may take a long time for SSRS to produce the report.  For example, adding lots of drill downs to sub-reports adds a substantial amount of extra output.  The easiest way to determine this is to export the report produced in the browser to MHTML.  You may be surprised by the size of the output.  This is one area where Visual Studio will have very different performance than a browser.

Obviously, transmitting large reports over slow networks adds to the rendering time (from a user's perspective).  In our organization, this transmission can add from an extra half second to go across town to an extra 20 seconds to go across the Atlantic ocean.  This is a bit difficult to measure precisely without a tool, but an empirical measure should give you a good enough answer.

Finally, there is the browser itself.  Chrome is MUCH faster than IE for rendering SSRS reports.  If you do use IE, check the compatibility view settings--SSRS should be faster with it off.  Also in IE, you may want to toggle the setting for Accelerated graphics.  In our organization, some users see better performance with it on, some see better performance with it off.